# How to use htaccess out of www folder in wamp server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

i want to use htaccess in the folder like this:

```
C:\wamp\www2\
```

its work in C:\wamp\www\ (default folder of wamp server) but not about above folder.
how can i make htaccess to work under www2 folder?
i use www2 for SSL requests over https
OS:win server 2008
regard.

Comment: why don't use C:\wamp\www\folder1 & C:\wamp\www\folder2
because it direct using http://localhost/folder1 and http://localhost/folder2

Comment: also you can try this http://kuppalli.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/setup-multiple-sites-on-your-local-machine-using-xampp-or-apache-2/ auto direct using port

Comment: ¿How is the actual htaccess file, if exists?

Comment: -Huei:i don't want my folder be accessible from http://mysite/folder2 and https://mysite/folder2
i am going to try your link tnx :) <br/>
-Felipe Alameda A:i want protect https root folder using htaccess and just access it only from one address,look at my above  answer tnx too

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have a proper `<Directory>` directive. You probably have something like this somewhere in your default WAMP config:

```
<Directory C:\wamp\www\>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The important part is `AllowOverride`. When this is set to `All` or a specific value, Apache will look for .htaccess files and configure itself at runtime based on the contents.

You probably just need to add a similar `<Directory>` section for your `c:\wamp\www2\` directory.

Comment: when i use your offer, "Basic authentication" dose not work for me but other command like "deny from all" work! i want use Basic authentication,whats the matter?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are experiencing with basic authentication?

Comment: i want to my HTTPS folder completely be separate from HTTP folder and also i want to protect my HTTPS document root using Apache basic authentication.

Comment: @user678955 You're asking multiple questions now, this is no longer about .htaccess but about virtualhost configuration.